# google sheets character limit

Tags: excel, upload, google-sheets

My Excel spreadsheet contains cells which are validated (via a macro) to allow a maximum of 200 characters to be entered.
When uploading to Google Drive, the sheet has changed the macro to normal data validation using the below formula:

```
=LTE(LEN(G5),(200))
```

However, an error message appears on each cell affected (G5:I297). Is there another way to validate the entries to prevent anyone entering more than 200 characters per cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Data Validation on Google Sheets simply have a custom formula set as:

```
=LEN(G5)<=200
```

Comment: How can I apply the restriction to the entire column? (In example, you have mentioned for only one cell)

Comment: Few years late, but if anyone is wondering:

Validation formulas use relative references. So to apply it to the whole column, just select that whole column, and then start the number from the first row, e.g. `=len(a1)<=200`. It will apply to the whole column.